# Find the parametrization for the curve in which the plane cuts a surface

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I need to find a parametric equation for the curve for which the plane $z=2$ cuts the surface $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y ^2}$

I'm not sure how to proceed. If the plane cuts the surface at $z =2$ and $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ then how do I find x, y and z in terms of $t$? Do I need two separate variables? For example...

$$x = s^2 - t^2$$
$$y = s^2 - t^2$$
$$z=2$$

I'm just guessing really, can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one parameter (say $t$), as the intersection of two surfaces is a curve. In this case the projection of the intersection to the $xy$ plane is a circle of radius 2 centered at the origin, so for example: $x=2\cos(t), y=2\sin(t), z=2$ will do.